# Can't change HTTP URL from 3rd party extension to HTTPS

Tags: magento2.3, third-party-module, https

We have an extention that communicates to our client's products system. That gives us live Prices, stock updates,s etc. They told us to change the URL in Magento from HTTP to HTTPS.

When I looked under MagentoRoot/App/Code/Module/Model/service/Endpoint.php I found this. And I have a feeling this is the reason it won't accept HTTPS.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace KraftMedia\AutodataCore\Model\Service;

use \KraftMedia\AutodataCore\Exception\UndefinedRequestTypeException;

class Endpoint
{
    const GET_REQUEST = 'GET';
    const POST_REQUEST = 'POST';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory
     */
    private $httpClientFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
    ) {
        $this->httpClientFactory = $httpClientFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $endpoint
     * @param  string $type
     * @param  array  $params
     * @param  mixed $logger
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEndpointData(string $endpoint, string $type, array $params, $logger = null)
    {
        $httpClient = $this->httpClientFactory->create();
        $httpClient->setUri($endpoint)
            ->setMethod($type)
            ->setConfig(['verifypeer' => 0])
            ->setAdapter('Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl');

        $queryArray = [];

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if ($type == self::GET_REQUEST) {
                $queryArray[$key] = $value;
                $httpClient->setParameterGet($key, $value);
            } elseif ($type == self::POST_REQUEST) {
                $httpClient->setParameterPost($key, $value);
            } else {
                throw new UndefinedRequestTypeException('Undefined request type.');
            }
        }

        $response = $httpClient->request();

        if ($logger) {
            $logger->info('Request: ' . $httpClient->getUri(true) . $this->getUriQuery($queryArray));
        }

        try {
            return $this->getFormattedReponse($response, $logger);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($logger) {
                $logger->info($e->getTraceAsString());
            }
            return [];
        }
    }

    public function getUriQuery($queryParams)
    {
        $query = '?' . http_build_query($queryParams, null, '&');
        $query = str_replace('+', '%20', $query);

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * @param  \Zend_Http_Response $response
     * @param  mixed               $logger
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFormattedReponse(\Zend_Http_Response $response, $logger = null): array
    {
        $responseBody = $response->getBody();
        if ($logger) {
            $logger->info('Content-Type: ' . $response->getHeader('Content-Type'));
            $logger->info('Response body: ' . $responseBody);
        }
        switch ($response->getHeader('Content-Type')) {
            case 'text/xml':
                $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($responseBody);
                /** @var string @json */
                $json = json_encode($xmlObject);
                $data = json_decode($json, true);
                break;
            case 'text/html':
                $data = json_decode($responseBody, true);
                break;
            case 'application/json':
                $data = json_decode($response, true);
                break;
            default:
                $data = [];
                break;
        }

        return is_array($data) ? $data : [];
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I need to change or add to make it work?

Comment: Do you have an error message? It looks as if something gets logged there, but only the exception trace and not its message. Also, no idea why they're using `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl` when `Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl` is available. Although they both should work with HTTPS

Comment: Hi, thanks for your awnser.

No, as far as we can see there is no error message. Out client can see the request from our side, is just that we do not get any info back. They could not either see any error from their side.

Comment: Look into Magento‘s var/log directory and there system.log, debug.log, exception.log. Also check your Webserver / PHP error log files. If $logger is the default logger, you should find something. If not, check if $logger is a custom logger from this module, and try to find out the log file name.